# How do I draw a time series that shows the amount of change in data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, visualization

For example, I have data such as:

```
18:00:00     0
18:00:01    -1
18:00:02    -1
18:00:03    -1
18:00:04     2
18:00:05    -3
18:00:06     1
18:00:07     2
18:00:08     3
18:00:09     4
18:00:10     5
18:00:11     4
18:00:12     3
18:00:13    -1
18:00:14     2
18:00:15     8
18:00:16    11
```

I want to draw waves according to the following points:

```
(-1,18:00:03)
(2,18:00:04)
(-3,18:00:05)
(5,18:00:10)
(-1,18:00:13)
(11,18:00:16)
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear, what's the rule to achieve the result

Comment: Explain the logic behind your output.

Comment: The output will be the graph that contains only positive and negative waves.

Comment: Are you asking how to get such pairs or how to draw them?

Comment: Yes, I ask how to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I thin I understand how to select the points. You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to create groups depending on the changes of signs of the values ​​of the series.

To differentiate the groups you can use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). I leave the **detail** of the result of the series that is used to form the groups.

Then I created a function to take the values ​​according to the criteria that I think you want to adopt and has been applied through [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
my_serie=pd.Series([0, -1, -1,-1 , 2, -3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, -1, 2,8,11],time_serie)

#creating Serie to plot
def get_value(x):
    if len(x)>=3:
        return x.iloc[2]
    elif len(x)>=2:
        return x.iloc[1]
    else:
        return x.iloc[0]
groups=((my_serie.shift()*my_serie)<1).cumsum() 
serie_to_plot=my_serie.groupby(groups).apply(get_value)
#tuple of Serie to plot
s_tuple=(*zip(serie_to_plot,serie_to_plot.index),)
#Show the serie an tuple
print(s_tuple)
print('-'*50)
print(serie_to_plot)
```

---

```
((0, 0), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (-3, 3), (3, 4), (-1, 5), (11, 6))
--------------------------------------------------
0     0
1    -1
2     2
3    -3
4     3
5    -1
6    11
dtype: int64
```

---

```
#Creating figure
plt.figure()
serie_to_plot.plot(figsize=(10,10))
plt.figure()
serie_to_plot.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,10))
```

Output images:

[image]

---

[image]

**Detail**

```
groups

2019-10-18 18:00:00    0
2019-10-18 18:00:01    1
2019-10-18 18:00:02    1
2019-10-18 18:00:03    1
2019-10-18 18:00:04    2
2019-10-18 18:00:05    3
2019-10-18 18:00:06    4
2019-10-18 18:00:07    4
2019-10-18 18:00:08    4
2019-10-18 18:00:09    4
2019-10-18 18:00:10    4
2019-10-18 18:00:11    4
2019-10-18 18:00:12    4
2019-10-18 18:00:13    5
2019-10-18 18:00:14    6
2019-10-18 18:00:15    6
2019-10-18 18:00:16    6
dtype: int64
```

Other figure:

```
#Creating figure
plt.figure()
serie_to_plot.plot(figsize=(10,10))
serie_to_plot.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: I checked your answer. You identified all the points and draw a graph.The important thing is the amount of change in the data.
Look between 18:00:05 and 18:00:10.
The change here is positive.
It should be indicated by only one line with a starting point of -3 and an ending point of +5.
You have 4 lines for this range in your code.It should look similar to this: https://imgur.com/n9XvVoz

Comment: I did not noticed it. I have corrected the solution. Please check it and rate my answer

Comment: Excuse me!
I made a mistake in points and fixed the error.
Please see this code: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KY9tYgKhwj/)
There is an increase from **6th** seconds to **10th** seconds.
But there was a decrease in **11th** and **12th** seconds.
And the code didn't catch it.
I'd appreciate it if you could figure it out.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know what you mean